# jQuery "on click by id" in Wordpress not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-events

I've read a lot of similar questions and tried implementing the solutions, but none of them works for me.

This is my code within the page:

```
<button id="hello" type="button">Try it</button>
```

And this is the script in the header:

```
$('#hello').click(hello);

function hello(){
    alert('inside hello function');
};
```

The only way I could get this exact code to work was when I put the function call directly into the button, like this:

```
<button id="hello" type="button" onclick="hello();">Try it</button>
```

But the problem with this is that Wordpress strips that as soon as I switch to the visual page editor.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you try `jQuery` instead of `$`?

Comment: Is the button created dynamically?

Comment: Please make sure that id remains consistent and use this:
$('body').on('click', '#hello', function(e) {
  return hello();
});

Comment: You won't get jquery to work in Wordpress if it's written as $(some code) instead, it should be jQuery(some code).

Comment: I fully agree with the duplicate flag

Answer (score 0):

You should encapsulate your code with the $(document).ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hello').click(hello);
    function hello(){
        alert('inside hello function');
    };
});
```

And you really don't need a named function for this kind of event handling, you could write your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hello').click(function(){
        alert('inside hello function');
    });
});
```

Comment: Because we need **yet another** answer to this question?

Comment: WordPress uses jQuery compatibility mode, $ will not work unless you pass it as a reference to a closure: (function($) { //your code here })( jQuery );